# Vertical mouse tracking reversed in OS X Lion at EFI Login Window

Tags: mouse, osx-lion, tracking

I am using a Razer Deathadder 3500dpi mouse and in 10.7, the vertical tracking is inverted at the EFI login window. I have FileVault enabled, so this is the password entry screen immediately after boot before any drivers from the encrypted system partition are loaded. I tried installing the official Razer driver (currently 3.0.0) with no success. I have since uninstalled the driver and am sort of stuck.

---

Additionally, I am seeing problems with assigning the "Show Desktop" shortcut to any mouse button in System Preferences > Mission Control. No matter which button I assign it to it will not work. I never had a problem with either of these in 10.6.

EDIT: The "Show Desktop" shortcut is temporarily solved by turning off the shortcut, logging out, then logging back in and turning it back on (after each boot).

Comment: You may want to consider breaking these up into two different questions. When you say "reversed" tracking, is do you mean like the new system default, or the traditional orientation?

Comment: No, I mean like when I physically move my mouse up, the arrow cursor goes down and when I move it down, the arrow goes up. (But left goes left and right goes right.)

Comment: Oh, _weird_. Do you see the same behavior with the standard mouse or trackpad?

Comment: No. Maybe this is a problem with third-party laser mice? Or multi-button mice?

Comment: The only reason for this that I can fathom is that perhaps that mouse is able to invert itself on a firmware level. When you cycle profiles with the button next to the IR sensor, is there any change in behavior?

Comment: I assume you mean on the mouse (it's a laser mouse), and no, it doesn't. Interestingly enough, when using the Recovery partition, it track correctly. Perhaps the EFI boot environment reads only raw mouse data?

Comment: I have the same mouse; at least mine uses an IR sensor, not a laser. I'll see if I can duplicate the behavior, but I'm still not clear on where this is happening. This is just a boot password screen, not the user login, correct?

Comment: Correct—at the [boot] login window to decrypt the HDD.

Comment: Mine does the same thing. Here's a vote!